# Javascript Abstract Class with Object create

Tags: javascript, inheritance, abstract-class

This is my Abstract class:

```
var Animal = function(){
    this.name = ''
    this.legs = 0;
    throw new Error("cannot instantiate abstract class");
}
Animal.prototype.walk = function(){ console.log(this.name+ " walked")};
```

Creating a new Concrete Class:

```
var Dog = function(){} ;
```

Now I want to make a concrete class Dog to inherit from abstract class Animal.  I tried both ways below.  Which one is the standard?:

```
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
```

OR

```
Dog.prototype = Animal.prototype
```

I also tried `var Dog = Object.create(Animal)`which gave me an error.

Comment: The standard way of extending a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) is to use [`extends`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends).

Comment: @str if you are in ES6 maybe, but the OP seems to be not

Comment: take a look @ this link might help https://coderwall.com/p/r47jlw/advanced-javascript-class-abstract-class-method

Comment: @smnbbrv There are JavaScript transpilers. So is there a reason to *not* use ES6+?

Comment: ES6 sounds like a new standard.  So what do developers do before ES6 exists?

Comment: You cannot throw error in constructor unless you are overriding it complete to avoid it

Comment: @str there are millions of reasons to not have ES6. The author does not have one so it should be respected I think

Comment: @smnbbrv Then name one good reason. The author never specifically mentioned that he wants to stick with ES5 *in the question* so mentioning a feature available in JavaScript today should be allowed. Don't you think? But now that the OP commented that he does not want to use ES6, it seems worthless to discuss this further.

Comment: @str ok reasons: 1. legacy project where you don't want to spend any time to configure babel 2. you are working in a strict enterprise environment and you are not allowed to use the technologies that are not on the list 3. your developers don't know ES6 and you don't want to introduce more complexity to the system because they are all e.g. Java developers and they simply don't need to learn another technology, etc. etc. etc. The author does not use ES6 class so your comment about `extends` does not make any sense. But people like you are always right, so keep going :)

Comment: @smnbbrv "But people like you are always right, so keep going :)" Oh OK. We have different opinions on the topic, so there is clearly something wrong with me. Good talk.

Comment: @smnbbrv.  ES6 is cool, but I have an interview coming up and they sounded like to just stick with ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `Animal` class you can make `if` check to see if the current `constructor` is `Animal` and throw an Error if it is. When you call parent constructor inside `Dog` and inherit from prototype you also need to set its constructor pointer to `Dog`.

```js
var Animal = function() {
  this.name = ''
  this.legs = 0;
  if (this.constructor == Animal) {
    throw new Error("cannot instantiate abstract class");
  }
}
Animal.prototype.walk = function() {
  console.log(this.name + " walked")
};

function Dog() {
  Animal.call(this);
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype);
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

var inst = new Dog;
inst.name = 'lorem';
inst.walk()
```